# Encontrar valor primera fila y primera columna para hacer una query

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Necesitaría hacer una query con dos variables al realizar click en un link de una celda:

1. Valor de la columna
2. Valor de la primera fila

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|  Name  |   Open   |   Close  |
+--------+----------+----------+
| user1  |     0    |     1    |
| user2  |     3    |     0    |
| user3  |     1    |     1    |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Y tengo la ventana modal que por ejemplo si hago click en el numero **3** debería guardar los valores "**Open**" y "**user2**" y de esa forma poder realizar una query:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">            
<?php include("conn.php");                 
$result = mysql_query("Select * from table where status = 'Open' and Name = 'user2'");               
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $test['id']; 
    echo"<div class='form-group'>";
    echo"<label for='s'>".$id." ".$city."</label>";
    echo"</div>";
}
mysql_close($conn); 
?> 
</div>
```

Que debería de adaptar para hacerlo? Gracias!

Comment: 1) porque no usas una tabla para definir `open` y `close` en la cual le puede asignar un solo valor; por ejemplo `0` para `open` y `1` para `close. 2) si usas un `while` toma el `id` asi `<a href="cerrar.php?id=<?=$test['id']?>Cerrar</a>"` y en `cerrar.php` creas un `update` para cambiar el valor. Se entiende?

Comment: no entiendo bien la pregunta! podrias ser mas especifico!

Comment: necesito detectar a partir de la celda que selecciono el nombre de su columna (arriba del todo) y el nombre de la fila (izquierda del todo). Es por eso que si escogiera el "3" pues las variables serian 2: Open y user2